# How can I view the User/Library/LaunchDaemons folder within the finder?

Tags: macos

Within the finder I can view the contents of User/Library and can see many folders there, however I cannot see a folder called LaunchDaemons.

However if I navigate to the Library folder from the terminal command line then LaunchDaemons is visible.

How can I make it appear in the Finder?

I've tried this command but it didn't have any effect

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (at least by default) no LaunchDaemons folder in the user Library. You may be navigating to one of the other Library folders in Terminal. You can check this with the commands `pwd` (which prints the full path to the current folder -- if it doesn't start with /Users/youraccountname/Library, you aren't in your user Library) and `open .` (which opens the current folder in the Finder -- and again, I'm pretty sure it won't be inside your user Library).